# Accessing kissmanga.com HTML with Python

Tags: python, html

I am trying to access the HTML of pages like http://kissmanga.com/Manga/Shokugeki-no-Soma so that I can make a function that lets me know when new chapters of manga are added. However, my attempts to access the code have not been successful, because of the website's requirements/securities. What are some ways I can get past this to access the website's HTML?

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://kissmanga.com/Manga/Hajime-no-Ippo')
print (resp.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very far away from being able to actually do the requests but you can get some ideas from the Kiss anime plex plugin, they do have a working python module that does all their requests through python:

https://github.com/Twoure/KissNetwork.bundle